# React Plotly: How to share zoom state across multiple subplots

Tags: reactjs, plotly, plotly-react

I am using `react-plotly.js` in my application and it appears that documentation is scarce on how to configure a shared x-axis across multiple subplots and am wondering if others have found success in configuring the `<Plot />` to get that outcome.

In my case I have 3 subplots stacked vertically. I am looking for the outcome where, when I zoom in on one of the subplots, the others will be zoomed in as well at the same scale.

Here are some snippets of code that I have:

```
import Plot from "react-plotly.js";

function MyComponent() {

  const layout = useMemo(
    (): Partial<Plotly.Layout> => ({
      grid: { rows: 3, columns: 1, pattern: "independent", subplots: ["xy", "x2y2", "x3y3"] },
      autosize: true,
      xaxis: { anchor: "y", domain: [0, 0.99], showticklabels: false },
      xaxis2: { anchor: "y2", domain: [0, 0.99], showticklabels: false },
      xaxis3: {
        anchor: "y3",
        domain: [0, 0.99],
        showticklabels: true,
        title: {
          text: "Time",
          font: {
            size: 16,
          },
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        anchor: "x",
        domain: [0.67, 0.93],
      },
      yaxis2: {
        anchor: "x2",
        domain: [0.33, 0.59],
      },
      yaxis3: {
        anchor: "x3",
        domain: [0, 0.26],
      },

      margin: {
        t: 15,
        b: 75,
        l: 80,
      },
      legend: {
        x: 1,
        y: 0.5,
      }
    }), []
  );

  return (
    <Plot layout={layout} config={{ autosizable: true }} data={[...]} />
  )

}
```

Hoping someone has managed to get this working and can share insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a [`matches`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-matches) (or [`scaleanchor`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-scaleanchor)) constraint on the axes, eg. to link the x axes :

```
const layout = useMemo(
  (): Partial<Plotly.Layout> => ({
    grid: { rows: 3, columns: 1, pattern: "independent", subplots: ["xy", "x2y2", "x3y3"] },
    autosize: true,
    xaxis: { anchor: "y", matches: 'x3', domain: [0, 0.99], showticklabels: false },
    xaxis2: { anchor: "y2", matches: 'x3', domain: [0, 0.99], showticklabels: false },
    xaxis3: {
      anchor: "y3",
      domain: [0, 0.99],
      showticklabels: true,
      title: {
        text: "Time",
        font: {
          size: 16,
        },
      },
    },
    // ...
  }), []
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks like `matches` is not part of the layout config fields in the React package but `scaleanchor` is and setting that did the trick!

Comment: side question related to the general post, would you happen to know what causes zoom state to reset whenever a chart update occurs in the React package? I am polling for chart data at a set interval and every time the new data comes in, any zoom state that I applied gets reset to the default zoom scale which is pretty annoying.

Comment: Well I don't know much about react.. Using plotly.js only, you would use the method [`Plotly.restyle()`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) for updating the chart data while preserving the layout state (including the zoom range). It seems with react (if you can't use the restyle method) you would have to listen for layout updates and apply the changes to the Plotly.Layout manually, otherwise `<Plot layout={layout} ...>` will always be (re-)rendered with the initial layout definition.

Comment: Thanks for following up! I actually ended up finding the solution thanks to another SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519850/plotly-react-keep-zoom-and-rotation-between-re-rendering) that pointed out the `uirevision` field that is part of the `Layout` object that we can set.